# Change catalog in Tomcat DataSource pool

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, database-connection

How can I change the database catalog in a Tomcat DataSource pools?
I tried:

```
datasource.getConnection().setCatalog("newcatalog");
```

but it doesn't work, maybe because I'm not changing the catalog for all connections and not for new ones.

Comment: Define "doesn't work": do you get an exception, or does nothing happen. That said, changing the catalog on a connection from a connection pool is a risky thing to do; I wouldn't be surprised if some connection pool implementations disallow it.

Comment: Simply it doesn't change the catalog.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [JDBC Data Sources](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources) section of the official Tomcat documentation you can make use of the `defaultCatalog` parameter in your configuration of the `DataSource`.

For instance:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDatasourceName"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="dbusername"
        password="dbpassword"
        driverClassName="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"
        url="jdbc:hsqldb:myDatabase"

        <!-- use the following catalog -->
        defaultCatalog="newcatalog"
/>
```

For a detailed listing of the attributes available have a look at *Common Attributes* section of the [Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes) docs, which describes `defaultCatalog` as follows:

> defaultCatalog  -- (String) The default catalog of connections created by this pool.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok I will try it, but I need also a method to refresh all already opened connections otherwise some of them may have the old catalog